# I can't write a method to get StringSet from SharedPref

Tags: java, android, list

I've encountered issue and maybe you guys can help me. I'm creating Shopping list app for android.
In this code below everything works:

```
List<String> list,listRecipe;
ListView listView,listViewRecipe;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getArrayList();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void getArrayList(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> mySetdownloaded = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("List", NotFoundSet());
    if (mySetdownloaded.size() == 0){
        list =  new ArrayList<>();
    }
    else {
        list = new ArrayList<>(sharedPreferences.getStringSet("List", NotFoundSet()));
    }
}
```

But when i make changes in my getArrayList Method so i can use it not only with one LIST but more (added argument) it's not working. I just get "App stopped working" on start

```
List<String> list,listRecipe;
ListView listView,listViewRecipe;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getArrayList(list);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void getArrayList(List<String> lists){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> mySetdownloaded = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("List", NotFoundSet());
    if (mySetdownloaded.size() == 0){
        lists =  new ArrayList<>();
    }
    else {
        lists = new ArrayList<>(sharedPreferences.getStringSet("List", NotFoundSet()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second snnipet you call `getArrayList(list)`, but `getArrayList()` doesn't return ANYTHING. And after you try to call `list` at

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

but `list` it's nothing, not even null, so you'll get `nullpointerexception` and crashes your app... You have to, at least, make `getArrayList` return something and assign to the attribute `list`, OR you don't pass `list` as argument, and try to access it as `this.list` instead `lists`.

Answer (score 0):

My final working code is:

```
public List<String> getArrayList(String nameOfSavedFile) {

    List<String> list;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> mySetdownloaded = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(nameOfSavedFile, NotFoundSet());
    if (mySetdownloaded.size() == 0) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    } else {
        list = new ArrayList<>(sharedPreferences.getStringSet(nameOfSavedFile, NotFoundSet()));
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }

}
```

Thanks for help ;)